# android phonegap plugin for epson sdk printer

Tags: android, printing, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to know if there is a phonegap plugin to print with epson printer sdk:
the sdk is here:
https://pos.epson.com/developers/LicenseAgreement.htm?AssetId=26316&ReturnUrl=/posindex/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals the answer is NO, at least not one that's publicly listed.

You might find [this Phonegap printer plugin](https://github.com/EionRobb/phonegap-print-plugins) useful.

But for an Epson-specific plugin, you'll probably need to either write a plugin yourself or pay someone to do so.

Comment: I hate to say, but I agree